# How to locate an element from Amazon page without using xpath or CSS path?

Tags: java, html, selenium, automation, css-selectors

1. Go [here](https://www.amazon.com/international-sales-offers/b/?ie=UTF8&node=15529609011&ref_=nav_navm_intl_deal_btn).
2. Try to locate the checkbox button Books with Inspector
3. Click on checkbox button to be selected

4.
 [image]

I try to iterate and to find the unique identifier "Books".
If you know another way to do click without to iterate is fine.
I used this lines of code:

```
List<WebElement> elements = new ArrayList<WebElement>(obj.findElements(By.cssSelector("span.a-label.a-checkbox-label")));
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        if (element.getText() == "Books"){
            System.out.println("");
            element.click();
        }
else
            System.out.println("Condtition from if is not true");
    }
```

Comment: You need to compare strings using `equals()` method.

Comment: Don't works I try if (element.equals("Books")){

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve without iterate, please locate the element by xpath with this value: `//label[contains(., 'Books')]//input`.

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[contains(., 'Books')]//input"));
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly find the element by using its text in the xpath.
You can do it like:

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='widgetFilters']//span[@class='a-declarative']//span[contains(text(),'Books')]"));
element.click();
```

And if you want to parameterise the xpath and want to fetch it using a string then you can do it like:

```
String filterName = "Books";
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='widgetFilters']//span[@class='a-declarative']//span[contains(text(),'"+filterName+"')]"));
element.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find check box for Books using xpath.

```
//div[@id='widgetFilters']//span[text()='Department']/parent::div/following-sibling::div//span[contains(text(), 'Book')]/parent::label/input[@type='checkbox']
```